# How to make a clickable image which invokes an action with parameters

Tags: image, jsf-2, commandlink

I want to have a clickable image which sends two parameters to my action on click. I tried the following with `<h:graphicImage>`.

```
<h:graphicImage url="/pic/down.png" alt="download">
    <h:outputLink action="#{file.download}">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{file.id}"></f:param>
        <f:param name="name" value="#{file.name}"></f:param>
    </h:outputLink>
</h:graphicImage>
```

However, it didn't work. How do I properly achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier if you know [basic HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/). A clickable picture in plain HTML look like this:

```
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

However, what your JSF code is generating is this (rightclick, *View Source* in browser to see it):

```
<img src="..."><a href=" ..." /></img>
```

This is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) HTML. You need to swap them.

Further, I'm not sure if this is result of carelessly fiddling/shooting-in-the-dark, but the `action` attribute is not supported in `<h:outputLink>`. You perhaps intented to use `<h:commandLink>`.

So, all with all, this should do:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{file.download}"> 
    <h:graphicImage value="/pic/down.png" alt="download" />
    <f:param name="id" value="#{file.id}" />
    <f:param name="name" value="#{file.name}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

*(make sure that this is placed in `<h:form>`)*

I'm however unsure how it makes sense to pass properties of `#{file}` back to apparently the very same `#{file}` instance as where you're invoking the action. You may as well just omit those `<f:param>` things and access the properties directly in the action method.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{file.download}"> 
    <h:graphicImage value="/pic/down.png" alt="download" />
</h:commandLink>
```